# Modify array parameter from inside subshell

Tags: zsh

Is it possible to `shift` or assign a value to an array parameter from inside a subshell?

Example code:

```bsh
arr=(a b c)
(shift arr)
echo $arr
# prints: a b c
# should print: b c
```

Comment: The answer to the question you asked is no, end of story. There may be a way to do what you actually want to do, but you need to [ask about what you want to do instead of asking about something that can't actually help you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Thank you, I know how to accomplish what I want, I just happen to be a particularly curious and stubborn fellow

Comment: FWIW, `shift` only shifts the positional parameters by the amount specified. With `set a b c d; arr=2; shift arr; echo $*` would output "c d" as you shifted the positional parameters by 2. To shift another array, you'd use `arr[1]=()` (for the equivalent of `shift`/`shift 1`). `shift` can also be written `argv[1]=()` or even  `1=()`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas the [ZSH builtin](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html) `shift` accepts either a numeric param (how many places to shift) or one or more name params (which array to shift) or both. Anyhow thank you for the tip

Comment: `shift arr` is `shift <arithmetic-expression>`. To shift an array other than `$argv`, you need both the arithmetic expression and `<name>` as in `shift 1 arr` (thanks for making me realise that btw).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas excuse me for correcting you on this. If you skip the `<arithmetic-expression>`, then a default of `1` is used. Try for example `arr=(a b c) ; shift arr ; echo $arr`

Comment: Seems you're right, my bad. Looks like `shift arr` is `shift 1 arr` if `arr` is declared as an array and `shift arr argv` otherwise (see `argv=( a b c d ); arr=1+1; shift arr; typeset -p argv`), I can't say I like that ambiguous API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the whole point of subshells, to run a portion of code in a copy of the current *shell execution environment* (see details in [the POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_12) for `sh`), so as to preserve the original one, so it's the whole point that any change to variables made in the subshell would be lost after termination of the subshell.

Traditionally, that is done by the shell forking a process and run the code in the child while the parent waits for its termination.

POSIX doesn't mandate that and ksh93 at least implements `(...)` subshells by carefully restoring the original environment upon return of the subshell without forking a process if that can be avoided (though sometimes failing to do so properly in some corner cases).

`zsh` does fork a process for that like most other shells. There are exceptions for optimisation, like when a `(...)` subshell is the last command in a `zsh -c` script:

```
$ zsh -c 'zmodload zsh/system; echo $$; (echo $sysparams[pid]; ps; ps)'
21085
21085
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
   1839 pts/4    00:00:00 zsh
  21085 pts/4    00:00:00 zsh
  21086 pts/4    00:00:00 ps
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
   1839 pts/4    00:00:00 zsh
  21085 pts/4    00:00:00 ps
```

It's the same 21085 process above that executed `zsh`, interpreted the subshell and even executed the last `ps` command.

It's enough to set a `trap` to invalidate that optimisation, the point being that it's only done if zsh can guarantee that nothing will be run by the shell after the subshell returns.

For the child process to be able to change the value of a variable in the parent process, it would need to do things like attach `gdb` to that process and inject code in it to change internal memory structures in that process.

If you wanted to get the value of an array as defined by a subshell you'd need the subshell to pass its definition to the parent. That could be for instance via:

```
eval "$(
  # also a subshell using $(...)
  arr=( a b c )
  typeset -p arr
)"
```

Then `typeset` will output `typeset -a arr=( a b c )` (or `typeset -g -a arr=( a b c )` if called within a function), which once `eval`uated will cause the same variable to be created in the parent.

By the way, instead of:

```
shift arr
```

I would use:

```
shift 1 arr
```

or:

```
arr[1]=()
```

The `shift arr` piece of code is ambiguous as it  means different things (`shift 1 arr` vs `shift arr argv`) depending on whether `arr` is declared as an array variable or not. Using `shift 1 arr` makes it more obvious that it's the former you want.

Answer (score 2):

A subshell is a different process, it can't modify the parent process.